# Simple value assignment with attr_accessor or attr_writer wont work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

For some reason @store object with three attributes won't assign the third value(generated token string).The model has **user_id**, **product_id** and **token_string**.But when it comes to **token_generate function** nothing is assigned,and end up with **nil** in the token_string column in the database .**Product_id** and **user_id** are saved perfectly in the database though.What is going on here?Thank you in advance.

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'digest/sha1'

  attr_accessor :token_string

  before_save :token_generate

  def save_with_payment 
     #Until here the object has user_id and product_id attribute values
     save!
  end

  private

  def token_generate
    self.token_string = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("random string")
  end
end
```

controller

```
def create
  @store=Store.new(params[:store])

  if @store.save_with_payment
    redirect_to :controller=>"products",:action=>"index"
  else
    redirect_to :action=>"new"
  end
end
```

Comment: If token_string is a field in the database, why do you have attr_writer :token_string in the model declaration? That most likely overrides the database accessor.

Comment: can you post the logs when you try to save?

Comment: in the log shows ,product_id and user_id values are inserted and token_string field is nil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@SrdjanPejic is correct, try removing the `attr_accessor :token_string` line which is likely blocking setting the :attributes hash value needed for the INSERT statement.